# Setting timeOut in javascript on changing display of element

Tags: javascript

I have a simple script that hides and shows certain element on the site by changing display to either "none" or "block". I want it to be animated, meaning that elements will slowly fade-out. I'm fairly new to javascript and I know that there is setTimeout and setInterval, but I'm not sure how to use it. How can I "animate" this functions? Here is my code:

```
var rysunki = document.querySelectorAll(".rysunek");
var projekty = document.querySelectorAll(".projekt");
var btnAll = document.getElementById("allItems");
var btnProjekty = document.getElementById("projects");
var btnRysunki = document.getElementById("drawings");

function removeDrawings() {
    var i;
    for (i = 0; i < rysunki.length; i++) {
    rysunki[i].style.display = "none";
    };
};
function showDrawings(){
    var i;
    for (i = 0; i < rysunki.length; i++) {
    rysunki[i].style.display = "block";
    };
};
function removeProjects() {
    var i;
    for (i = 0; i < projekty.length; i++) {
    projekty[i].style.display = "none";
    };
};
function showProjects() {
    var i;
    for (i = 0; i < projekty.length; i++) {
    projekty[i].style.display = "block";
    };
};
function showAll() {
    showProjects();
    showDrawings();
}

btnProjekty.addEventListener("click", function(){
    showProjects();
    removeDrawings();
});
btnRysunki.addEventListener("click", function(){
    removeProjects();
    showDrawings();
});
btnAll.addEventListener("click", showAll);
```

Is it even possible? Should I add something with opacity of the elements I'm hiding?

No jQuery please, only Vanilla JS.

Edit:
As requested, here is the HTML. Basically there are 2 different elements:

```
<figure class="projects-panel__item col-md-3 projekt">
    <a href="img/projekty/1.jpg" data-lightbox="gallery" data-title=""><img src="img/1.jpg" alt="" /></a>
</figure>
<figure class="projects-panel__item col-md-3 rysunek">
    <a href="img/1.jpg" data-lightbox="gallery" data-title=""><img src="img/1.jpg" alt="" /></a>
</figure>
```

Comment: Provide your html code.

Comment: First tip. Please do not mix polish language with english. Seriously, just write in english. I am giving You this advice as a polish dev with few years of experience in polish, and european market ;)

And the second tip. Actually You don't need to change display with JS, use mix of JS and CSS instead. 

More info in my answer ;)

Comment: @grzesiekgs yeah I know, I will change that later when it's done :)

Answer (score 0):

Heres an simple example of how to do it with mix of JS and CSS.

In JS I am just changing class of container, in response to button click.

In CSS I've defined **transition: opacity** (this is how stuff is being animated) on **.projects** and **.drawings**

I've also added two classes which will modify value of opacity on those two classes above.

Feel free to ask questions if You do not understand something.

```js
const container = document.querySelector('#container')

const showDrawings = () => {
  container.classList.remove('showProjects')
  container.classList.add('showDrawings')
}

const showProjects = () => {
  container.classList.remove('showDrawings')
  container.classList.add('showProjects')
}

const showAll = () => {
  container.classList.add('showDrawings')
  container.classList.add('showProjects')
}

document.querySelector('#drawingsButton').addEventListener('click', showDrawings)

document.querySelector('#projectsButton').addEventListener('click', showProjects)

document.querySelector('#allButton').addEventListener('click', showAll)
```

```css
.drawings,
.projects {
  display: inline-block;

  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;

  opacity: 0;

  transition: opacity .3s .1s;
}

.drawings {
  background: red;
}

.projects {
  background: blue;
}

.showDrawings .drawings {
  opacity: 1;
}

.showProjects .projects {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div class="drawings"></div>
  <div class="projects"></div>
</div>
<button id="drawingsButton">Drawings</button>
<button id="projectsButton">Projects</button>
<button id="allButton">All</button>
```

Comment: Regarding animation - it's exactly what I'm looking for, but without changing "display" I will have a lot of blank space in my container in which all these elements are. Even with opacity: 0 these elements will still be there.

Comment: Yep that is indeed true. You can do two things :

1. Create animation instead of transition, and animate opacity from 0% to 99% of animation, and at the end of animation, simply put display: none;
Ofcourse this would make things little bit more complicated, since You are going to need separate class (and animation) to show, and hide elements.

2. Attach ontransitionend event to Your elements (I would suggest some event delegation out there). It will fire when transition ends, then You could check if element has specific class applied, and then You can modify the display.